# sklearn One Hot Encode. ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

**I am new at coding with sklearn, I need to encode 3 columns of my dtaset, I tried encoding only one column but it sent me an error**

> ---

*ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _hstack(self, Xs)
614                                             force_all_finite=False)
--> 615                                 for X in Xs]
616             except ValueError:
5 frames
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Vikings'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _hstack(self, Xs)
615                                 for X in Xs]
616             except ValueError:
--> 617                 raise ValueError("For a sparse output, all columns should"
618                                  " be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.")
619

ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.*

**When I tried to encode the 3 columns it send me the result in tuples, but I need it encoded and not in tuples.**

*(0, 25)    1.0
(0, 62)   1.0
(0, 86)   1.0
(1, 3)    1.0
(1, 44)   1.0
(1, 99)   1.0...*

**My code is as follows**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ds = pd.read_csv('nfl_per.csv')

X = ds.iloc[0:2789,4:-1].values
y = ds.iloc[0:2789,-1].values

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
print(X)
```

**For encoding the 3 colums I use:**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ds = pd.read_csv('nfl_per.csv')

X = ds.iloc[0:2789,4:-1].values
y = ds.iloc[0:2789,-1].values

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0,1,2])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
print(X)
```

**but again, I don't want it in tuples but encoded.**

**The dataset that I am using is the following:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wn5coKQ5BRWS1Bll5po2H45unWtPLqTX/view?usp=sharing

I will appreciatte any guidence and suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

<s>OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)</s>

The above was deprecated since version 1.2 and is removed in 1.4 use `sparse_output` instead.

```
OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)
```

Comment: For newer scikit versions use `sparse_output=False`